# Random message at random time

Tags: java, multithreading, console-application, java-8, java-7

So, I have a console java app. It has a menu and several submenus.
A *random message*(I already have list of messages, so need to choose one of them) to be shown at *random time*, only when user *at the "main menu"*, not submenus.

Not asking you to give me a code, just algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the logic how to achieve this?  Here is some 
Pseudocode to get you started

```
On.ChangeMenu{
    if(currentmenu=='main menu'){
        start_random_message_timer();
    }
    else{
        stop_random_message_timer();
    }
}

function start_random_message_timer(){
    Thread timerthread=new Thread(function(){
        int minseconds=30;
        int maxseconds=200;
        int timeouttime=1000;
        int randomtime=rand(minseconds,maxseconds);
        int currenttime=time();
        int nexttime=currenttime+randomtime;
        timeouttime=currentime+timeouttime;
        while(currenttime<timeouttime){
             while(currenttime<nexttime){

                      //this is the time wasting loop
                       currenttime=time(); 
               }
             //here currenttime just passed nexttime
             var message=selectrandommessagefromarrayofmessages();
             show(message);
             randomtime=rand(minseconds,maxseconds);
            nexttime=currenttime+randomtime;
        }
     });
     timerthread.Start();
}

function stop_random_message_timer(){
  var currenttimerthread=gettimerthread();
   currenttimerthread.stop();
}
```